# .htaccess. Как перенаправить все запросы, кроме одного

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Я хочу, чтобы все запросы, которые начинаются на backend/ перенаправлялись на `./backend/public/index.php`, а все остальные перенаправлялись на `index.html`. На данный момент ВСЕ запросы перенаправляются на index.html. Как это исправить?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Если путь начинается с backend/, то перенаправить на ./backend/public/index.php
# UPD. Добавил флаг [L], но всё равно все запросы перенаправляются на index.html
RewriteRule ^backend/* ./backend/public/index.php [L]

# Иначе перенаправить все запросы на index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: флаги `[L,QSA]` в помощь

Comment: @teran Можете пожалуйста оставить пример, как это использовать в моём случае? Вроде ставлю, как нужно, но никак не могу понять, почему не работает

Comment: как нужно это как? дополните вопрос.

Comment: @teran Дополнил

Comment: структуру директорий от корня проекта укажите еще. и `./` уберите

Comment: @teran Добавил структуру директорий

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1/ !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*?)/?$ public/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).+?)/?$ public/$1/ [L,NC]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]